# Research Information System

Tags: university, funding

My employer is considering implementing [Atira PURE](http://atira.dk/en/pure/) to help manage grant applications and grant funding at the university level.
Seems like it might have some benefits... but could also add a costly and unnecessary layer of overhead.

Any experience with this or the equivalent?

Comment: Is this On-topic? Seems more relevant to administration, than academia.

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham Academia is not only about research, administration is a big part of it… FAQ says “inner workings of research departments”, which seems to cover this question.

Comment: Administration is an inseparable part of academia. But about direct relevance of this question to research community ...

Answer (score 3):

We use *pure* at our university to register publications. Maybe we also use it for other purposes, but I have only been affected by the publication part.

The registration of publications is a necessity, because the university uses this information to distribute money to different research groups (e.g. each year there is a bonus based on the number of published peer-reviewed articles in a [recognised journal](http://dbh.nsd.uib.no/kanaler/).

I've occasionally been assigned the task for my group to make sure all our articles were "registered in *pure*", and I can say that it works reasonably well. The interface is not superb, and I wouldn't like to work with it all day, but it gets the job done. I don't know anything about the alternatives.

It does also generate a fancy and completely useless person graph.

[image]